# how to restart the app with single process?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I want to restart my app, but I follow the tutorial and add systemtray icon. every time restart the app, the systemtray not disappear, I found the app not really restart by some reason.

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    EXIT_CODE_REBOOT = 122
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.restart_button = QPushButton('restart')
        self.restart_button.clicked.connect(self.onRestart)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.restart_button)

        self.systray = QSystemTrayIcon(self)
        icon = self.style().standardIcon(QStyle.SP_TrashIcon)
        self.systray.setIcon(icon)
        self.systray.show()

    def onRestart(self, checked):
        QApplication.exit(self.EXIT_CODE_REBOOT)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    currentExitCode = MainWindow.EXIT_CODE_REBOOT
    while currentExitCode == MainWindow.EXIT_CODE_REBOOT:
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        mainwindow = MainWindow()
        mainwindow.show()
        currentExitCode = app.exec()
        app = None
```

each time restart the app, the previous system tray always existing, it is like it start an other process, I want the only process and not consuming any resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code and it works fine on Linux, but I also found similar reports ([like this](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/pipermail/pyqt/2015-April/035879.html)) about persistent icon after quit on Windows.

While doing a `self.systray.hide()` *before* quitting should be fine enough, I think that deleting the object from Qt's side (not by using `del`) might be better:

```
    def onRestart(self, checked):
        self.systray.deleteLater()
        QApplication.exit(self.EXIT_CODE_REBOOT)
```